# How to test LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean using Spock

Tags: java, spring, spock

How can I test my db connection using spock? I know how to do this using `JUnit` and the test pass, but when I am trying do similar thing using `Spock` I am getting `NullPointerException` and Cannot invoke method `getDataSource()` on null object.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DatabaseConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
class DatabaseConfigTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean;

    def "Should connect to database."() {
        when:
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getDataSource().getConnection()
        then:
        notThrown(SQLException.class)
    }
}
```

How to test the DB connection using Spock, my class that is responsible for database configuration is `DatabaseConfig.class`

Comment: Have you added the `spock-spring` dependency? You don't need other annotations than `@SpringBootTest`.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for.  Remove the ContextConfiguration and WebAppConiguration annotations.  Inject DataSource directly.

```
@SpringBootTest
class DatabaseConfigTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    def "Should connect to database."() {
        when:
        dataSource.getConnection()
        then:
        notThrown(SQLException.class)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to test the dataSource method, I want to test the LocalContainerEntityManager that contains all information about datasource and jpaProperties.